# Stubbing an es6 class function dependancy

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, prototype, sinon, stub

Imagine I have a Controller that validates some input, and uses a Service (es6 class) to execute some part of the business logic.

**Controller.js** (Object function)

```
const Service = require('./Service');

module.exports = {
  get: id => {
    //validates id
    return new Service().get(id);
  }
}
```

**Service.js** (ES6 class function)

```
class Service {
  constructor() {...}
  get(id) { return 'actual function'; }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

I wish to stub the get function in the service to test the Controller.

**Controller_test.js**

```
const Controller = require('../src/Controller.js);
const Service = require('../src/Service.js);

describe('Controller', () => {
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should use fake get function', done => {
    sandbox.stub(Service.protoype, 'get').callsFake(() => {
      return 'Fake has been called');
    });

    const result = Controller.get(id);
    expect(reuslt).to.equal('Fake has been called'); //returns 'actual function'
  });
});
```

So, to reiterate. I am unable to stub a class function used in an object function with sinon. I do not want to pas in extra arguments if I dont have to.

Comment: I am not completely sure but it seems like you stub the `Service.get` to return `Fake has been called`, but you are not really 'stubing' Controller.get thats why you keep getting the return value of the real function.

Comment: This is true, but I want to execute the real Controller.get function, and fake the Service.get function. I thought prototype would be global, even with modules in node

Comment: I am not that expert at testing but IMO if you are making unit test you can split what you are trying to achieve into 2 tests, then thats the whole point of unit testing. Test that `Service.get` returns a function (stub) , and separately test `Controller.get` with another stub. That is at least what I would do.

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen There is nothing wrong with you test code. It works (see my answer below where I have a link to a repo reproducing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your test code is correct

First of all: There is nothing wrong with your test code. It works!

I looked at it, and thought it looked correct, so I recreated it (removing spelling and syntax errors) [here](https://github.com/fatso83/forum-support-code/tree/master/stackoverflow-48787513). The test passes with flying colors. This means you are doing something different than what you assume.

In that repo I have also added support code in to demonstrate various approaches mentioned below.

## There are three issues presented:

1. What is a good way of controlling the dependency of `Controller`?
2. How do I test an exported singleton?
3. How should you model the test?

You'll find some good discussions on the Sinon issue tracker concerning #1, where [this](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263) would probably be of interest.

As you know Java, you'll probably know the two camps as Inversion of Control (*dependency injection* (pass in dependencies) and *IOC Containers* (give me something of type 'foo') - not much used in JS, except Angular). You also have [*link seams*](http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/), if you are familiar with Michael Feathers, which works at a lower level to replace code supplied by your module loader (`require` calls).

The latter would have enabled replacing the `Service` implementation like this:

```
// myServiceStub is at this point set up by you using Sinon
// use `sandbox.resetHistory()` to reset the stub between tests
const Controller = proxyquire('../src/Controller', { './Service' : myServiceStub });
// test that the stub is invoked as expected
```

In JS land you "need" a support library like`proxyquire` or `rewire` to use *link seams*,  so it's only natural that you resorted to manual dependency injection using a setter. While using link seams let's you avoid changing production code, it has the downside of also assuming intimate knowledge of the modules dependencies. DI at least lets you stay on the interface level.

The "dirty feeling" you mention in your own answer probably arises from two things:

- you are changing *the module* (global state), not any created *instance* of `Service`
- you are exposing knowledge about the module's direct dependencies that isn't possible to see using a direct relationship in the test (a linter could complain about `Service` not being used).

Dependency injection comes in mainly two forms: constructor injection (I include factory methods in this definition) or setter injection. You can see both [here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263).

Constructor injection wouldn't work well here, as you are working with a Singleton object created at module definition time. Replacing the `Service.js` module in itself using a setter (`export __setService(MyStubClass){ Service = MyStubClass; }`) would not change the fact you are changing the *module*, which might affect tests running after this one if you don't clean up correctly (for instance adding a `__reset` method). This is basically what you have done in your own supplied answer.

You can find running, working examples of both ways in the [mentioned repository](https://github.com/fatso83/forum-support-code/tree/master/stackoverflow-48787513) in the `link-seams` and `dependency-injection` branches.

Personally, I don't think testing the `Controller` in itself using unit tests gives much value and I try to avoid singleton modules (in any language). I'd test the `Service` implementation and make an integration test (on the HTTP layer) and replace the Service being used with a fake to control the response. The actual `Service` seems much more interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works as intended, but it feels hackish. Your answer and links gives me a better understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution I've found: Exporting the Service from the controller and stub it through the controller.

**Controller**

```
const Service = require('./Service');

const Controller = {
  get: id => {
    //validates id
    return new Service().get(id);
  }
}

module.exports.default = Controller;
module.exports.Service = Service;
```

**Test**

```
const Controller = require('../src/Controller.js');

describe('Controller', () => {
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should use fake get function', done => {
    sandbox.stub(Controller.Service.protoype, 'get').callsFake(() => {
      return 'Fake has been called');
    });

    const result = Controller.get(id);
    expect(reuslt).to.equal('Fake has been called'); //returns 'actual function'
  });
});
```

This feels dirty! A better solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can see some alternatives here: https://github.com/fatso83/forum-support-code/tree/master/stackoverflow-48787513

(Branches: `master`, `link-seams`, `dependency-injection`)